# Trying to use xPath on an xml document created in memory not from a file

Tags: java, xpath, dom4j

I am exporting data into an xml file.  I am looping through a database exporting various data and need to check the xml document to see if it exists already as I'm exporting data.

When I try using xPath to query the xml document it returns null.  Do I have to save the xml file then reload it for xPath to work?  Am I doing something wrong?  Here is my test code below.  Note, I tried using xmlDoc.selectNodes as well as xPath.  Still no love

Here is the console output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root>
  <authors>
    <author>
      <name>Steven Rieger</name>
      <location>Illinois</location>
    </author>
    <author>
      <name>Dylan Rieger</name>
      <location>Illinois</location>
    </author>
  </authors>
</root>
org.dom4j.tree.DefaultDocument@e26948 [Document: name null]


public class TestXML
{

    public static void writeXmlDoc( Document document ) throws IOException
    {

        OutputFormat format = OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint();
        // lets write to a file
        XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter( new FileWriter( "c:\\temp\\output.xml" ), format );
        writer.write( document );
        writer.close();

        // Pretty print the document to System.out
        writer = new XMLWriter( System.out, format );
        writer.write( document );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        org.dom4j.Document xmlDoc;
        List<Node> authors = null;
        Element author = null;
        try
        {
            xmlDoc = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
            Element root = xmlDoc.addElement( "root" );
            Element authorsElement = root.addElement( "authors" );
            Element author1 = authorsElement.addElement( "author" );
            author1.addElement( "name" ).addText( "Steven Rieger" );
            author1.addElement( "location" ).addText( "Illinois" );

            Element author2 = authorsElement.addElement( "author" );
            author2.addElement( "name" ).addText( "Dylan Rieger" );
            author2.addElement( "location" ).addText( "Illinois" );



            writeXmlDoc( xmlDoc );

//          authors = xmlDoc.selectNodes( "/authors" );

             XPath xpathSelector = DocumentHelper.createXPath("/authors");
             authors = xpathSelector.selectNodes( xmlDoc );

            for (Iterator<Node> authorIterator = authors.iterator(); authorIterator.hasNext();)
            {
                author = (Element) authorIterator.next();
                System.out.println( "Author: " + author.attributeValue( "name" ) );
                System.out.println( "  Location: " + author.attributeValue( "location" ) );
                System.out.println( "  FullName: " + author.getText() );
            }

            System.out.println( xmlDoc.toString() );
        } catch ( Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query retunrs null because authors is not the root of the xml. You may use this xpath instead:

```
XPath xpathSelector = DocumentHelper.createXPath("/root/authors/author");
```

The other problem is that you first store the name and state as child elements of the author, but later you try to read them as attributes.
See https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_el_vs_attr.asp
You may try to read them in the loop like this:

```
System.out.println("Author: " + author.selectSingleNode("name").getText());
System.out.println("  Location: " + author.selectSingleNode("location").getText());
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.  I'm not a big xml guy and this was most helpful.  I though there was a way to get all authors using xpath without having to know the parent.

Comment: So I got the code working, AGAIN THANK YOU!  I am having one last issue.  I am trying to do a quick search by one of the elements and I'm not having any success. I've tried various query strings but nothing ever gets selected.  Can you see what I'm missing?

String xPathQueryStr = "/root/authors/author[@location='Wisconsin']";
  
authors = xmlDoc.selectNodes( xPathQueryStr );
if( authors.isEmpty())
{
    XPath xpathSelector = DocumentHelper.createXPath( xPathQueryStr );
    authors = xpathSelector.selectNodes(xmlDoc);
}

authors is always and empty list

Comment: It's again because '@' selects attributes, you should use xpath without it; see here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp